# Is it possible to run actions directly from the map canvas?

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to run actions directly from the map canvas in Qgis?
If yes how can I do that?

Comment: By "actions", do you mean functions like **Intersect**, **Interpolation** etc?

Comment: I mean actions in Qgis layer properties

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for the Run Feature Action tool. Please see the docs for all options:

http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#actions-menu

> Actions can be invoked from either the Identify Results dialog, an Attribute Table dialog or from Run Feature Action (recall that these dialogs can be opened by clicking [image] Identify Features or [image] Open Attribute Table or [image] Run Feature Action).

Comment: underdark The <<run feature action>> works fine. My next step is to publish the project to geoserver. I hope <<action>> will also work there. Thanks